# Stop the system from converting HTML codes to correct characters

Tags: html, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and trying to put this case...when in

[image]

As much as I appreciate the automatic conversion of the [image] to é when the query runs (this website even does the same thing that's why I had to insert the pictures), I really want the query to look for title containing that term instead of the correct converted one. How can I get this fixed?

Comment: SQL Server **doesn't** do that. I assume you must be viewing the results (or constructing the query) in a web interface that doesn't escape the text correctly in the event the query or results contain something like that

Comment: Hi @MartinSmith, so you're saying that it's because the browse/platform I run this query on caused this issue?

Comment: yes. If you run it in SSMS you won't get this issue